# How to load comments previous comments on click button using angular js, ajax without blink

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

[image]

I have the following comments section When I click on load previous comments/click on load prevoius click the page scroll goes top but comments load successfully, but I want to load previous comments without any page scroll movement and page blink any help will be appreciated.
I am using the following code shown below.

```
   <div id="loadComment" style="height: 20px; margin-top: 10px;" ng-click="viewPreviousComments()" ng-hide="commentIndex==CommentData.length?true:false">
            <span style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px;"><a href="#">Load previous comments</a>
            </span><span style="float: right; padding: 0px 15px 0px 0px;"><span style="color: #fe6600;" ng-bind="commentIndex > CommentData.length ? CommentData.length : commentIndex"></span>&nbsp;of&nbsp;<span style="color: #fe6600;" ng-bind="CommentData.length"></span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="row comments  gsc-background" ng-repeat="comment in CommentData" ng-show="$index < commentIndex" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;">
            <img id="Img1" ng-src="{{comment.Image}}">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-11">
                <div class="member" style="padding-top: 5px;">
                    <a href="#" ng-bind="comment.CommentedBy"></a>
                    <span ng-bind="comment.Comment"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-11">
                <div class="member">
                    <time ng-click="focusSubCommentBox(comment.PKCommentID)" style="padding-left: 3px;" class="reply-like">Reply</time>&nbsp;&nbsp;-
                    <time ng-click="likeComment(comment.PKCommentID,false)" style="margin-left: 2px;" class="reply-like" ng-bind="comment.LikeUnlike"></time>
                    <i ng-show="comment.Likes > 0 ? true : false" style="border-left: 2px dotted rgba(254, 102, 0, 1); border-right: 2px dotted rgba(254, 102, 0, 1); padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px; margin: 0px 3px 0px 3px;" class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up">&nbsp;<span ng-bind="comment.Likes"></span></i>&nbsp;-
                <time ng-bind="comment.CommentDate |timeago"></time>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

   var app = angular.module('app', ['ngtimeago']);
    var id = document.URL.split("/")[4];
    var defaultUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/ShowContent.aspx")%>';
    app.controller('formCtrl', function ($scope, $sce, $timeout) {

        $scope.loadComments = function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                url: defaultUrl + '/LoadComments',
                data: "{'id':'" + id + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    var loadComments = angular.fromJson(result.d);
                    $scope.CommentData = angular.copy(loadComments);
                    $scope.commentIndex = Math.round(((25 / 100) * $scope.CommentData.length));
                }
            });
        };
        $scope.viewPreviousComments = function () {

            function innerFilter() {
                if ($scope.commentIndex == Math.round(((25 / 100) * $scope.CommentData.length))) {
                    $scope.commentIndex = Math.round(((50 / 100) * $scope.CommentData.length));
                }
                else if ($scope.commentIndex == Math.round(((50 / 100) * $scope.CommentData.length))) {
                    $scope.commentIndex = Math.round(((75 / 100) * $scope.CommentData.length));
                }
                else {
                    $scope.commentIndex = $scope.CommentData.length;
                }


                $('html, body').animate({
                    'scrollTop': $("#loadComment").position().top
                }, 500).slideDown(500);

            }
            $scope.filtering = false;
            $timeout(innerFilter, 2500);

        };
    });
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is due to the `href='#'` in your anchor. Try `href="#/"` for instance, and see if that works.

Comment: Just remove the `#` in the `href="#"` since you are using angularjs.

Comment: yes man it worked it's because of href='#', you solved my problem (Y) thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

We can Load using ajax call, Then Bind with the UL LI TAGS... Append Option..

Happy Coding...!@

Dinesh